# Rails Capybara Test has empty Instance Variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, factory-bot, poltergeist

I have a controller sending in a list of vendors to my controller, and on normal view it's working fine.

```
class VendorsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :html, :json

  def index
    @vendor_categories = VendorCategory.where(:is_top_level => true)
    @vendors = Vendor.includes(:vendor_tier, :vendor_categorizations, :vendor_categories).order('vendor_tier_id DESC, name ASC')

    respond_with @vendors
  end
end
```

In my view I have the following two lines:

```
= debug @vendors
= debug current_user.user_vendor_choices
```

which, again, are working if I view it in the browser.  However, if I test it with Capybara and RSpec, it's empty.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'Vendors' do
  before do
    category = create(:vendor_category)

    5.times do 
      vendor = create(:vendor)
      vendor_categorization = create(:vendor_categorization, vendor: vendor, vendor_category: category)
      p vendor
      p category
      p vendor_categorization
    end

    visit signup_path

    @new_user = sign_up
  end

  before(:each) do
    visit destroy_user_session_path
    visit new_user_session_path
    sign_in @new_user
    visit vendors_path
  end

  it 'should save selected vendors', js: true do
    p Vendor.includes(:vendor_tier, :vendor_categorizations, :vendor_categories).order('vendor_tier_id DESC, name ASC').count
  end

end
```

`Vendor.all` and the above `Vendor.includes...` both return values, but for some reason in my test it's not showing anything... getting a `Capybara::Element not found`.

**UPDATE**

For testing purposes, I created the Vendors directly with the controller:

```
  def index

    @vendor_categories = VendorCategory.where(:is_top_level => true)
    4.times do
      Vendor.create({name: 'Test McTesterson', vendor_tier_id: 1})
    end
    @vendors = Vendor.includes(:vendor_tier, :vendor_categorizations, :vendor_categories).order('vendor_tier_id DESC, name ASC')

    respond_with @vendors
  end
```

Spec passes.  What the--?  This must be a FactoryGirl issue, or for some reason my records are deleted before it can run the test?  Consoling the objects after I create them is showing a record with an ID, which I guess doesn't prove that it's putting them in the database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my Database Cleaner activities defined in my spec_helper were a little too vigorous.  I had:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```

I had to get rid of the second chunk, so it now reads:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

end
```

And it works!  Not really sure why... any ideas (aside from the obvious, before it was calling database cleaner before/after each test)?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I cursorily glanced at this question, not sure you even need the help anymore, but I think the reason this is failing is a fundamental set up issue that your answer is just patching around.

When you're running a `js: true` spec (by the way, `js: true` should be on the `describe` line, not the `it` line), short version, Capybara works in different threads, so instance variables created in a `before` block, unlike with regular Rspec testing, are not available in the spec. To make them available, you have to use a `truncation` cleaning strategy.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:each, js: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

TL;DR when running a js test, truncation is basically required (unless obviously you're running js tests that don't require any database interactions). When running all other tests, use transactions (because it's also much faster). I guess your answer replicated this to some extent =)